# Intersection of vector subspaces $W_i$ of a vector space $V$ is a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

On the internet, there are several proofs, but only with two vector subspaces.

I am trying to do a proof

Let $C$ = $\bigcap W_i \in I$
where $W_i$ is a vector subspace of a vector space $V$

$C$ $\subseteq V$
As $C$ $\subseteq W_i$ $\land W_i$ $\subseteq V \Rightarrow C$ $\subseteq V$

$\vec{0}\in C$
As $\vec{0} \in W_i \Rightarrow \vec{0}\in C$

$\vec{u} + \vec{v}\in C$
Suppose that $\vec{u}, \vec{v}\in C$
As $W_i$ is vector subspace $\Rightarrow \vec{u} + \vec{v} \in W_i \Rightarrow \vec{u} + \vec{v} \in C$

$\alpha \vec{u} \in C$
Suppose that $\vec{u}\in C \land \alpha \in \Bbb{K}$
As $W_i$ is vector subspace $\Rightarrow \alpha\vec{u} \in W_i \Rightarrow \alpha\vec{u}\in C$

Therefore $C$ is a vector subspace of $V$

Is my proof correct? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks mostly correct but the writing is very difficult to follow. Here's a more succinct way, using the [one-step vector subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test).

Let $\{W_i:i\in I\}$ be a collection of subspaces of a vector space $V$ and let $W=\bigcap_{i\in I} W_i$.

Note that $\vec 0\in W_i$ for each $i$ since each $W_i$ is a subspace of $V$. It follows that $\vec 0\in W$ so $W\neq\varnothing$.

Now, let $\lambda\in \Bbb K$ and $u,v\in W$. Then $u,v\in W_i$ for each $i$. Since each $W_i$ is a subspace, it follows that $u+\lambda v\in W_i$ for each $i$. Hence $u+\lambda v\in W$. This proves that $W$ is a subspace of $V$.